# ShellTileSchedule not working in windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I am using ShellTileSchedule to schedule a local notification after 2 hours and the problem is sometimes it does not get triggered and sometimes it gets triggered right away.
I waited for two hours and Tile did not get updated but then i unpin the tile and pin it again and , Look and behold my notification is there.
Is there any limitation in tile schedule or am i doing it wrong please see code below

```
        ShellTile primaryTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();   
        StandardTileData standardTileData = new StandardTileData();
        standardTileData.BackgroundImage = null;
        standardTileData.Title = "WE Have A Notification!";
        standardTileData.Count = 1;
        standardTileData.BackTitle = "MY FARM .";
        standardTileData.BackContent = name;
        standardTileData.BackBackgroundImage = null;

        ShellTileSchedule scheduler = new ShellTileSchedule(primaryTile, standardTileData);
        scheduler.Recurrence = UpdateRecurrence.Onetime;
        scheduler.StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(7200);
        scheduler.Start();
```

P.S: I have tried giving different values in Scheduler.startTime but no use .

Answer (score 1):

The ShellTileSchedule only supports valid intervals as defined in the [enumaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.updateinterval%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

The only way to have tiles update on a frequency of every 2 hours will be to send the updated details via a push notification.
See [How to send and receive Tile notifications for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202970%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more information.